# Configuration parameters in pm2 to display colors in console

Tags: node.js, colors, terminal, config, pm2

I use pm2 to keep my node.js app alive, I am starting my app with a configuration file that looks like this:

```json
{
    "name"        : "myApp",
    "script"      : "app.js",
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "ignoreWatch" : ["node_modules","public"],
    "watch"       : true,
}
```

Additionally I am using the package **colors** to identify different types of messages but all the logs lose their color when I run the command

```
pm2 logs
```

My question is: what can I add to my configuration file to be able to see the colors in console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When I did use a other logger modules, (like a [colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors), [tracer](https://github.com/baryon/tracer) )

(In my case, 
`var logger = require('tracer').colorConsole();` as logger )

```
{
    "args": [ "--color" ]
}
```

this `"args": "--color"` keeps my logger's log color.

Insert that code in your pm2 script,

then you can see your color log by that command: `pm2 logs "id" --raw` (id is a pm2 id)

```
{
    "name"        : "myApp",
    "script"      : "app.js",
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "ignoreWatch" : ["node_modules","public"],
    "watch"       : true,
    "args": [
        "--color"
    ]
}
```

The process is needed to `pm2 stop`, `pm2 delete` and new pm2 start using script.

Comment: which is equivalent to `pm2 start app.js -- --color` if you don't use a config file, as seen @ https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1719#issuecomment-151446644

Comment: I think `pm2 delete` implies `pm2 stop`, so you only need the latter.

Comment: Good question, good answer - exactly what I needed! I found that this works with `pm2 reload ecosystem.json` but not with `pm2 reload <id>` for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I found I also needed to add this option for debug to my `pm2 process.json` file

```
"env": { "DEBUG_COLORS": true }
```

then can view colored debug logs with both `pm2 logs` and `pm2 logs --raw`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `--raw` switch. Like this —

`pm2 logs --raw`

Comment: Strange. It works for me. What version of `pm2` are you on?

Comment: I updated to 0.14.3 and I don't get the error anymore, thanks :)