# Why did my SSH server's colors get eaten when running via PM2?

Tags: ssh, terminal, pm2

I wrote a simple SSH server using [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2) that tries to print colored output when a user connects. Here is the code:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import {Server} from 'ssh2';
import chalk from 'chalk';

console.log('normal');
console.log(chalk.green('green'));

const server = new Server(
    { hostKeys: [fs.readFileSync('../../DEPLOY/data/https/certificate.pem')] },
    (client) => {
        console.log('connect');
        client.on('error', (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        }).on('authentication', (context) => {
            console.log('authenticated');
            context.accept();
        }).on('ready', () => {
            console.log('ready');
            client.on('session', (accept) => {
                console.log('session');
                const session = accept();
                session.once('shell', (accept) => {
                    console.log('shell');
                    const channel = accept();
                    channel.write('normal\n');
                    channel.write(chalk.green('green\n'));
                });
            });
        }).on('close', () => {
            console.log('closed');
        });
    }
);

server.listen(3333, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3333');
});
```

I first print out `'normal'` without color, then I print out `'green'` in green just to test that [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) is working. Then I also send the colored and uncolored text over the ssh channel.

If I start my server using `npx ts-node <myfile>`, then it works properly on the server side:

[image: server with colors]

and on the client side:

[image: client with colors]

However, when I try to run the server with PM2, I don't get the colors on the server side:

[image: server with no colors]

nor on the client side:

[image: client with no colors]

I tried setting `DEBUG_COLORS=true` and I tried setting `FORCE_COLOR=1`, but neither of those seemed to do anything.

What is PM2 doing with my colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `--color` to the `args` in the ecosystem file, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            /* ... */
            args: '--color --myOtherArg',
            /* ... */
        },
    ],
};
```

Here's [another similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34363932/4476484) and [a github issue](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5537) for reference.